# Present Popover View Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

When I try to display a popover view controller programmatically it won't work and I don't know why.  I've copied from multiple sources on the web and nothing seems to work, I get the same error in the console every time showing `Warning: Attempt to present <AddFriendsPopoverViewController> on <MainPageViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`  I am lost and can't seem to figure out what the problem is, thanks in advance!

Here is my swift code in my `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
let addFriendsPopoverViewController = AddFriendsPopoverViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (PFUser.currentUser()?["numberOfFriends"])! as! NSObject == 0 {
        print(PFUser.currentUser()?["numberOfFriends"])

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddFriendsPopoverViewController") as! UIViewController

        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        let popoverMenuViewController = vc.popoverPresentationController
        popoverMenuViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        popoverMenuViewController!.delegate = self
        popoverMenuViewController!.sourceView = self.view
        popoverMenuViewController!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(
            100,
            100,
            0,
            0)

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I figured out that for a popover to work with iPhone the following code is required.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .None
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view is not in the view hierarchy until it has been presented and not during `viewDidLoad:`

Move your code to `viewDidAppear:`

```
 if (PFUser.currentUser()?["numberOfFriends"])! as! NSObject == 0 {

    addFriendsPopoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle =   UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
    let popoverMenuViewController = addFriendsPopoverViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController!.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceView = self.view
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    presentViewController(
        addFriendsPopoverViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: That did the trick, but i'm having trouble designating a size for it to show up over the present view controller, how could i go about doing that?

Comment: Did you init your addFriendsPopoverViewController from the storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did, I have updated my question with the instantiation code included.  It loads the popover but it appears full screen despite me setting the `preferredContentSize.`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working right but u can not write that presentViewController code in ViewDidLoad method because viewdidLoad call till that time controller itself it not presented thats why it's not allow to presentViewController .

Write that same code in..

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)

{
    var controller = UIViewController()
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor .greenColor()
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

***I have made it simple for multiple use and its ready to use and go. just copy and paste this extension***.

```
extension UIViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{

@discardableResult func presentPopOver(_ vcIdentifier: String, _ isAnimate: Bool = true,sender:UIView,contentSize:CGSize = .init(width: 100, height: 100)) -> (UIViewController){
    let popoverContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
    popoverContentController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    if let popoverPresentationController = popoverContentController?.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        popoverContentController?.preferredContentSize = contentSize
        popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
        if let popoverController = popoverContentController {
            present(popoverController, animated: isAnimate, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    return popoverContentController ?? UIViewController()
}

public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

public func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    
}

public func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool{
return true
}}

**how to use for presenting pop over on button click:-** 

   @IBAction func sortClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presentPopOver("PopOverVC", sender: sender)
   }

***presenting pop over and to get and pass data:-*** 
@IBAction func sortClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = presentPopOver("PopOverVC", sender: sender) as? PopOverVC
    vc?.arrayNames = ["name1","name2"]
    vc?.callBack = {name in
        print(name)
        vc?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```